# Critical points of a continuous linear operator between normed vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $L:V\rightarrow W$ be a continuous linear operator where $V,W$ are finite dimensional normed vector spaces. Let $D=\{x\in V\,:\,||x||\leq1\}$. Where does L take its maximum and minimum value on $D$? I have a feeling that it will be on the boundary of $D$. Please prove if so.

Comment: What do you mean by “maximum value”? Suppose, for instance, that $V=W=\mathbb{R}^2$ and that $L(x,y)=(x,y)$. What is the maximum value of $L$ on $D$?

Comment: I mean max of $||L(x}||$ for all $x$ in D where the ||.|| is the norm on $W$. @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum is always taken at $0$. If $\ker L=\{0\}$, it will be taken there and only there.

You are right about the maximum (unless $L\equiv0$, of course). Take $x\in V$ such that $\|x\|<1$ and that $L(x)\neq0$. Then $x\neq0$ and$$\left\|L\left(\frac x{\\|x\|}\right)\right\|=\left\|\frac{L(x)}{\|x\|}\right\|=\frac{\bigl\|L(x)\bigr\|}{\|x\|}>\bigl\|L(x)\bigr\|$$and $\frac x{\\|x\|}\in D$.

Note that the continuity of $L$ is useless and, besides, it holds automatically for linear operators on finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Why does $L(x)\neq 0$ imply $x\neq 0$?

Comment: @AnjaniGupta Because $L$ is linear and therefore $L(0)=0$.

Comment: Oh am really sorry for the blunder as I was treating $\neq$ as $=$ and was thinking abount the case when $Ker(L)\neq 0$.